# java.io.FileNotFoundException: data.properties (The device is not ready)

Tags: java

```
getting the below error while exporting to PDF file:-   

 java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Workspace\PricingTool\data.properties (The device is not ready)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at export.ExportToPdf$PageNumbersWatermark.onOpenDocument(ExportToPdf.java:1451)
        at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.initPage(Unknown Source)
        at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.open(Unknown Source)
        at com.lowagie.text.Document.open(Unknown Source)
        at export.ExportToPdf.CreatePDF(ExportToPdf.java:189)
        at export.ExportToPdf.doGet(ExportToPdf.java:130)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
```

Here is my code:

```
public void CreatePDF(Document document, PdfWriter writer,
            HttpServletRequest request) throws DocumentException {
        otherexpids = new ArrayList();
        int proj_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("proj_id"));
        int ver_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ver_id"));
        document.addAuthor("Infogain Corporation");
        document.addTitle("Online Pricing");
        writer.setPageEvent(new PageNumbersWatermark());
        writer.setEncryption(null, "pc123!".getBytes(),
                PdfWriter.AllowPrinting, PdfWriter.STANDARD_ENCRYPTION_128);
        document.open();
        Paragraph ph = new Paragraph("", header);
        ph.setAlignment("center");
        document.add(ph);
```

I want to export some records to a pdf file but while debugging i am getting error at **document.open()**

please help me on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: FileNotFound error usually means the file doesn't exist, or isn't in the place you're wanting to look for. That's why it stops at document.open(); try making sure there is a actual file named "data.properties" in the directory

Comment: Are you able to use the D: drive (using explorer)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13343502/4290096

Comment: thanks....it was really helpful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot Create New file: The device is not ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343502/cannot-create-new-file-the-device-is-not-ready)

Answer (score 0):

If you configured the path in your configuration file then check the location. In my case, I changed my drive from E to D